# Cannot allocate memory error in Rails (when creating folder locally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, memory-management

I have a Rails app that gives me this error once in a while:

```
 Errno::ENOMEM
```

Error is coming from this function:

```
   def create_folder
    new_dir = self.id.to_s
    working_dir = '/home/user/files/'
   # THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR:
    %x[cd #{working_dir} && mkdir #{new_dir}]
    working_dir = working_dir + new_dir + '/'
    self.working_dir = working_dir
   self.save!
```

This error is happening from controller, which upon creation of model calls the above mentioned function...

Would be really grateful if someone points out how to deal with it..

I cannot see any pattern in why it happens or when..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record. The error went away the moment I started using Ruby's Dir.

So

```
%x[mkdir NNN] # THIS IS BAD
Dir.mkdir("BBB") # THIS IS GOOD.
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer. that closes this questions. thanks.